# AWS Cognito Pricing confusions

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm checking aws cognito pricing, their explain make me confuse. They wrote:

> Users who sign in through SAML or OIDC federation:
> For users who sign in through SAML or OIDC federation, the price for MAUs above the 50 MAU free tier is $0.015.

So What is differences between sign in directly with User Pool credentials and via SAML?

https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect a Cognito user pool to a SAML IDP (Azure, Okta, etc.) and use a Cognito App client to allow users to authenticate with your SAML IDP (i.e. log in with their company Okta account) and assign an AWS IAM role through the Cognito pool.

It is a bit more complicated to set up a SAML provider, but a common requirement for corporate applications. If you do not need to integrate with another IDP, then you can use the standard Cognito user pool, which is much cheaper.